# WordPress - How to use custom rest api endpoint to upload files

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, wordpress-rest-api

I'm creating some custom endpoints for a wordpress custom plugin.
I need to give to users the ability to upload some files when they will use the vue app that will hold the custom registration form I'm creating.

How I can include a nonce with the post request to make it more secure and how I will get the files in the custom endpoint? I will have more than one file input and all of them will be required for the registartion. My idea is to upload the file and add the link to the file into an user meta field.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are the users actual WP users or anonymous?

Comment: @ChrisHaas when they will register they are anonymous users

Comment: If you had real users I was going to suggest Application Passwords which would allow your Vue app to securely authenticate. I don’t know if a nonce would really help you for an anonymous API, since that scraped or automated. I think CORS would be a good solution to prevent remote sites hosting something. But otherwise, I think I’d just make sure that some verification process exists so that nothing uploaded is public until the verification succeeds.

Comment: @ChrisHaas how I can setup application password or cors in wp?

Comment: Here’s a pretty thorough article on [application passwords](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/) which includes a [minimal JS gist](https://gist.github.com/georgestephanis/44d16dfdd17bd18b9c45d1d5e6d7ec7b). This article shows you how to [conditionally enable CORS](https://linguinecode.com/post/enable-wordpress-rest-api-cors).